# Digital to Analog Converter Images in the Frequency Domain

Tags: analog, filter, dac

I have been reading the theory behind digital to analog converters. I'm still very confused on what causes images to appear in the frequency domain. For example, if I was using a DAC that was producing a 1 MHz signal at 40 MHz sample rate. I notice that I have harmonics in the frequency domain at 39 MHz and 41 MHz.

what causes that to happen?

I read that one way to help with that is to use a low pass filter at the DAC output or a reconstruction filter.

Would increasing my sample rate make these images have less power in the frequency domain?

Also, is the stair step response of the unfiltered sine wave produced caused by these images?

Meaning does it look like a stair case because of these images?

Comment: Don't the frequency bins go from \$-\frac12 f_s\$ to \$+\frac12 f_s\$? Just curious how you are able to *see* harmonics outside that range... Perhaps some more details could be added to your question?

Comment: *I notice that...* Are you noticing it in the fft of the signal? "*39MHz*" is expected as the fft magnitude would be symmetric about 40/2 MHz. But fft shouldn't even have a 41 MHz bin if the sampling frequency is 40MHz. DTFT will have it, but not fft.

Comment: I think the more accurate way of looking at this is that it is the staircase response of the DAC that generates the spurious frequencies you see, if the DAC output is unfiltered.  Think of this as a more complicated version of the serial clock.  Now determine what the frequency spectrum of that clock looks like.

Comment: If the signal looks like staircase, then, yes, a reconstruction filter (low pass) will help reduce the power in the images.

Comment: "Would increasing my sample rate make these images have less power in the frequency domain?".  No.  That would just shift the images around in the frequency domain, moving them higher up.  However, this does allow them to more easily be filtered out.

Comment: This wikipedia article has a detailed derivation:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold  As you suspected, the images are caused by the staircase shape of the output of a zero hold circuit.  The reconstruction filter removes the staircase form and therefore the images.  Not that zero order hold is an ideal model.  Real devices have finite bandwidth and so will always attenuate the images, at least to some extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the DAC is fed with samples at some rate, it can't directly output a perfect continuous analog sine wave from discrete samples, as the voltage is updated at some rate and between those updates the output is ideally constant and ideally the step is infinitely fast.

Therefore the output waveform has steps at the rate of the sampling rate, which means there is a frequency component at sampling rate, and since the step edge is infinitely fast, it has frequency components up to infinity. So this itself proves that the output can't output an analog sine wave from sampled data.

That is why it needs an analog reconstruction filter to remove the artifacts and leave the original waveform that was sampled.

So basically, you are modulating the sample data with impulses that happen at sampling rate, so it is a frequency mixer.

Another way to approach this is that each sample itself is output as a rectangular pulse that lasts for a period between two samples. A frequency domain representation of a rectangular pulse is a sin(x)/x waveform, meaning each sample has energy that extends up to infinitely high frequencies.

So it is the staircases and the frequency images that are not a separate things, but really they are just the same signal viewed in either in time domain or frequency domain

Comment: What is the relationship between the sampling frequency and the amount of bits in a DAC? I know now that the higher the number of bits, the more accurate the vertical resolution. I also know that the higher number of bits you have, the more staircase steps you will have. How does any of that relate to sample rate in the DAC?

Comment: The number of bits per sample has no relation to the sampling rate at all.